# Solving $\cosh(zx) = yx$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions, trigonometric-series

I am currently facing a problem where I have to solve the equation where $x\neq 0$:

$$\cosh(3.8x)=3.5x$$

Wolframalpha only outputs an array of numbers without much too it.

Does anybody know how i can resolve it?
I cant just simply use cosh-1 because of the fact that i have x on both sides.

Comment: Next time, please use the link to format your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, unless there's some important content in an image that you cannot relay with equations, please refrain from images.

Comment: Finally, this equation doesn't have any real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Change in exponential form $$\cosh(3.8x)=\frac{e^{3.8x}+e^{-3.8x}}{2}$$

Comment: That would mean $$7x=e^{3.8x}+e^{-3.8x}$$

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Letting $y = 3.8x$,
this is
$\cosh(y) = ay
$
with $a = 3.5/3.8
$
or
$\dfrac{\cosh(y)}{y}
=a
$.

Since
$\dfrac{\cosh(y)}{y}
\gt 1.5
$
for $x \ge 0$
(according to Wolfy),
there are no positive real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\cosh \left(\frac{19 x}{5}\right)-\frac{7 x}{2}$$ for which
$$f'(x)=\frac{19}{5} \sinh \left(\frac{19 x}{5}\right)-\frac{7}{2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=\frac{361}{25} \cosh \left(\frac{19 x}{5}\right)\quad > 0 \quad \forall x$$
The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{5}{19} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{35}{38}\right)\implies f(x_*)=\frac{1}{38} \left(\sqrt{2669}-35 \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{35}{38}\right)\right)\approx 0.600$$

The second derivative test shows that $x_*$ corresponds to a minimum and since $f(x_*)>0$, there is no real root.

If we look for the complex solution, first let $x=\frac{ 5}{19}y$ and then $y=a+i b$. Expanding, we need to solve
$$\cosh (a) \cos (b)+\frac{35  a}{38}+i \left(\sinh (a) \sin (b)+\frac{35 b}{38}\right)=0$$ From the real part, we have
$$b=\cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{35a}{38}  \text{sech}(a)\right)$$ Plug in the expression of the imaginary part.

So, we now need to solve for $a$
$$\sinh (a) \sqrt{1444-1225 a^2 \text{sech}^2(a)}+35 \cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{35a}{38} 
   \text{sech}(a)\right)=0$$ A quick plot reveals that the solution is close to $-1$; using this approximation, this gives $b_\pm\approx 0.93$.

Now, use Newton method with $x_0=-\frac 5{19}(1-i)$. The iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -0.263158+0.263158\, i \\
 1 & +0.070690+0.218730\, i \\
 2 & +0.248807+0.202118\, i \\
 3 & +0.242215+0.252746\, i \\
 4 & +0.245420+0.248767\, i \\
 5 & +0.245466+0.248783\, i
\end{array}
\right)$$